# Вывод данных пользователя в личный кабинет Джанго

Tags: python, django

Мне необходимо при авторизации в свой личный кабинет выводить автомотически данные фио и дату рождения. все вроде работает, но данные не выводяться

views.py

```html
def post(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Personal.objects.filter(fio=request.user)
    }

    return render(request, 'logistic/account.html', context)
```

account.py

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %}Личный кабинет{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet"  href="{% static 'logistic/css/account.css' %}">

</head>
<body>
    <div class = "body">
        <img src = "{% static 'logistic/image/1900/1900-background.png' %}"/>
    </div>
    <div id="window"></div>
    <form action= "" method="POST">
        {% for post in posts %}
        <h3>{{ post.fio }}</h3>
        <p>{{ post.date }}</p>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

models.py

```html
class Personal(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) #ключевое
    fio = models.CharField('ФИО', max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField('Дата рождения')
    username = models.CharField('Логин', max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField('Пароль',max_length=100, unique=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите, что возвращает `request.user`, он возвращает экземпляр user, а не его имя. А в поле `fio` хранится имя пользователя.